# Is there a way to detect when a Flash video has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I work on a website that embeds videos from many different websites, the number of sources run into the thousands. For YouTube, their JavaScript API allows a way to detect when the video ends and one can execute any function he wants at that time. But this will only work for the youtube videos. What about all the others?

So is there a global all applicable way to detect when the Flash video on a page has stopped playing using either javascript or action script? And by "stopped playing" I mean stopped playing when it reached the end and not just been paused half way.

P.S. There will always be one embedded video inside a `<div>` with the id `video` on the page.

Comment: Are you trying to do this within the ActionScript or from JavaScript? What player are you using?

Comment: I highly doubt it since it isn't even specific to one single Flash player.

Comment: @wecsam I'm guessing it has to be done from javascript (if that's even possible) since the players are from external websites over which we have no control. Players are whatever the source site offers, usually embedded via iframe or object code.

Comment: Ah, I can answer your question, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like YouTube provides an API, those players from those external websites have to provide their own APIs as well. There isn't an easy one-size-fits-all solution that you can implement in JavaScript.